# How to get cache images path

Tags: magento2, product-images, catalog, image-resizing, cache-images

I am showing [Listrak](https://help.listrak.com/en/articles/2407425-on-site-recommendations-website-integration) on site recommend product on my website.

Product images are very big, I need resizes images.

I have images name like `2/0/20mm.jpg` and I am appeding it with `https://example.com/media/catalog/product`

So it will be

> https://example.com/media/catalog/product/2/0/20mm.jpg

But i want

> https://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/fc6ca0131474e1299ecedb80f5002264/2/0/20mm.jpg

**Note**: I do not have product object, So can't load an get resized images that why need to get cache folder path so I will append image name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can search magento code for the hash function which creates that hash and copy parts of it to your code

Comment: Are you trying to access the Magento images from and external website and don't know the URL? I believe the hash part is the same for same image resize settings, so you could hardcode it

Comment: @Alex, Yes I thought same to find hash code but could not find. at the moment I have written hard coded hash value but when I flush catalogue cache from admin, will hash value will change ?

Comment: I think it shouldn't change. Only when you change the image format in the theme I guess

Comment: @Alex, Yes you are right, it is not changing hash after flush catalogue cache. we can hard code it. please add your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hard code the hash as it depends only on the image target format and mostly does not change.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the cache path (hash) of the small_image on PLP then you can get the following way.

1. Need to get the size of the small_image from view.xml.
2. Need to generate the directory hash.
3. Generate an URL, based on the hash.

**1. Step**
Inject this class into the constructor.

```
use Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface as ViewConfigInterface;
```

Then you can retrieve width and height like this. If the sizes are different in the GRID view then need to use category_page_grid instead of category_page_list. (But you can use any other id here.)

```
$imagesConfig =$this->viewConfig->getViewConfig()->getMediaEntities(
    'Magento_Catalog',
    'images'
);

$width = $imagesConfig['category_page_list']['width'];
$height = $imagesConfig['category_page_list']['height'];
```

**2. step**

Inject EncryptorInterface into the constructor.

```
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;
```

Then you need this function.

```
/**
 * Converting bool into a string representation
 *
 * @param array $miscParams
 * @return array
 */
private function convertToReadableFormat(array $miscParams)
{
    $miscParams['image_height'] = 'h:' . ($miscParams['image_height'] ?? 'empty');
    $miscParams['image_width'] = 'w:' . ($miscParams['image_width'] ?? 'empty');
    $miscParams['quality'] = 'q:' . ($miscParams['quality'] ?? 'empty');
    $miscParams['angle'] = 'r:' . ($miscParams['angle'] ?? 'empty');
    $miscParams['keep_aspect_ratio'] = (!empty($miscParams['keep_aspect_ratio']) ? '' : 'non') . 'proportional';
    $miscParams['keep_frame'] = (!empty($miscParams['keep_frame']) ? '' : 'no') . 'frame';
    $miscParams['keep_transparency'] = (!empty($miscParams['keep_transparency']) ? '' : 'no') . 'transparency';
    $miscParams['constrain_only'] = (!empty($miscParams['constrain_only']) ? 'do' : 'not') . 'constrainonly';
    $miscParams['background'] = !empty($miscParams['background'])
        ? 'rgb' . implode(',', $miscParams['background'])
        : 'nobackground';
    return $miscParams;
}
```

Finally, you can get the path like this:

```
$path = $this->encryptor->hash(
    implode('_', $this->convertToReadableFormat([
        'image_height' => $height,
        'image_width' => $width,
        'background' => [255, 255, 255],
        'angle' => null,
        'quality' => 80,
        'keep_aspect_ratio' => true,
        'keep_frame' => true,
        'keep_transparency' => true,
        'constrain_only' => true,
    ])),
    Encryptor::HASH_VERSION_MD5
);
```

**3. step**
You can use StoreManager to get the media URL and generate the URL.

{MEDIA_URL}/catalog/product/cache/{CACHE_PATH}

Comment: I had to pass `["area"=>"frontend"]` to `getViewConfig()` to get all formats.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a bash command to get the cache image file and delete it (optionally). I leave the source code below, maybe it will help someone.

In my `di.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regenarate_image" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Base\Console\RegenerateImages</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

and my Command:

```
    namespace Vendor\Base\Console;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
    use Magento\Framework\App\State;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
    use Exception;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\ImageFactory;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    
    class RegenerateImages extends Command
    {
        const IMAGE_ID = 'category_page_grid';
        const NAME_ARGUMENT = 'sku';
    
        /**
         * @var State
         */
        private $state;
    
        /**
         * @var ImageFactory
         */
        private $imageFactory;
    
        /**
         * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $productRepository;
    
        /**
         * @var Filesystem
         */
        private $filesystem;
    
        /**
         * @var File
         */
        private $file;
    
        /**
         * @param State $state
         * @param ImageFactory $imageFactory
         * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
         * @param Filesystem $filesystem
         * @param File $file
         * @param string|null $name
         */
        public function __construct(
            State $state,
            ImageFactory $imageFactory,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
            Filesystem $filesystem,
            File $file,
            string $name = null
        ) {
            $this->state = $state;
            $this->imageFactory = $imageFactory;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
            $this->file = $file;
    
            parent::__construct($name);
        }
    
        /**
         * @usage bin/magento vendor:regenarate_image {product sku}
         * @return void
         */
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this->setName('vendor:regenarate_image');
            $this->setDescription('Regenarate product image using the SKU');
            $this->addArgument(
                self::NAME_ARGUMENT,
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'Product Sku'
            );
    
            parent::configure();
        }
    
        /**
         * @param InputInterface $input
         * @param OutputInterface $output
         * @return int|void
         * @throws LocalizedException
         */
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {
            $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
            $sku = (string) $input->getArgument(self::NAME_ARGUMENT);
    
            try {
                $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
            }catch (Exception $error){
                $output->writeln("Cannot find product with SKU: {$sku} . More details". $error->getMessage());
                return;
            }
    
            $imageUrl = $this->imageFactory->create([
                'miscParams' => $this->getImageMiscParams(),
                'filePath' => $product->getData('small_image'),
            ]);
    
            try{
                $imageUrl = $imageUrl->getUrl();
            }catch (Exception $error){
                $output->writeln($error->getMessage());
                return;
            }
    
            $output->writeln("Cache Image Url: {$imageUrl} ");
    
            $afterCacheFolder = explode('cache/', $imageUrl);
            $afterCacheFolder = $afterCacheFolder[1];
            $output->writeln("Getting hash: {$afterCacheFolder} ");
    
            $mediaPath = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
    
            $catalogMediaImageCacheFolder = $mediaPath.'catalog/product/cache/'.$afterCacheFolder;
    
            $output->writeln("Full cache image file path: {$catalogMediaImageCacheFolder} ");
            
//optionally, if you want you can remove it !
            try {
                if ($this->file->isExists($catalogMediaImageCacheFolder)) {
                    $this->file->deleteFile($catalogMediaImageCacheFolder);
                }
            }catch (Exception $error){
                $output->writeln($error->getMessage());
            }
            $output->writeln("Finished!");
        }
    
        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getImageMiscParams() : array
        {
            return [
                'image_type' => 'small_image',
                'image_height' => 500,
                'image_width' => 500,
                'background' => [
                    0 => 255,
                    1 => 255,
                    2 => 255,
                ],
                'angle' => null,
                'quality' => 80,
                'keep_aspect_ratio' => true,
                'keep_frame' => false,
                'keep_transparency' => true,
                'constrain_only' => true,
            ];
        }
    }
```

Now if you run `vendor:regenarate_image {product sku}`, you will get the cache image patch and it will remove it.
Good luck !