# File show placeholder image, even existing

Tags: magento2.3.4, debugging

I imported files, but the cached image is the placeholder iamge.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

The media/catalog/product/cache/18076855f65e9b9019a33b25468c9e1d/filename.png URLs are fetched by the pub/get.php

You can start debugging from there.

Interesting point is
`\Magento\MediaStorage\App\Media::launch`

See if there is an exception thrown

```
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->setPlaceholderImage();
    }
```

This might give you more information.
Unfortunately this exception is not logged by Magento.

Other debugging entry points

`\Magento\MediaStorage\Service\ImageResize::makeImage`

Comment: Could you please help in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315646/how-to-get-cache-images-path ?

Comment: I want to get `18076855f65e9b9019a33b25468c9e1d` this.